# HP Office Jet K 60 Will Not Print

Tags: printing

> HP Office Jet K60
>
> Laptop: ASUS K501
>
> Ubuntu 14.04
>
> Driver HPLIP USB

Installed with no issue. Print box and print review and all other commands normal.

Problem:

`Error on executing PRINT command = configuration set-up`

How should I proceed?